# How to safely use cold storage

Tags: coldstorage

I am relatively new to cryptocurrencies and would like your feedback on how to safely generate paper wallets for BTC, ETH, LTC and XMR tokens. I intended to follow these steps:

1. Download and install Tails on a USB flash drive using the Tor
   browser.
2. Boot [Tails](https://tails.boum.org/) (without activating any persistent volume) and
   download an offline copy of the following paper wallet generators:
   [BTC](https://www.bitaddress.org), [ETH](https://www.myetherwallet.com/), [LTC](https://liteaddress.org/) and [XMR](https://moneroaddress.org/).
3. Disable any internet connection.
4. Generate the adresses and private keys using the paper walletsg enerators.
5. Hand write each of these adresses and private keys on a paper.
6. As a digital backup, save pdf files containing the adresses and private
   keys on a new USB flash drive.
7. Restart the computer in order to clear any trace of the private keys from the Tails USB flash drive.

Also, is there a safe way to verify that the recently generated private keys and adresses work properly (i.e. no bugs/mistyping)?

Please let me know if you spot a flaw or if you have any advice. Thank you for your inputs!